# How can I update the content in the page without using other html files

Tags: html, django, backend

I'm learning Django now and everytime I use an UpdateView or anything that changes the content of a form I always have to use other html files that have the form like author_update_form, is there a way to edit directly on the same page like how on youtube comments I can press on edit and I dont get directed to a different page?

Comment: You might have to use ajax.

Comment: Django has a separation between login and presentation so there's not really any built-in Django way for this

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to display the information as a form, prefilled with the object attributes and then save the instance when you receive post request.

```
form = ObjectForm(instance=object)
if(request.method == "POST"):
        form = ObjectForm(request.POST, instance=object)
        form.save()
```